# Disk 0 (C:) missing from Task Manager Performance Tab in Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, task-manager, windows-server-2012-r2, performance-monitor

In both Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012R2, I am missing my C: drive (which is Hard Drive 0 or Disk 0) from the *Performance* tab in Task Manager.

This used to work with Windows 8.1.

[image: Task Manager]

Comparison of 8.1 (left) and 2012R2 Task Managers, on 2 different systems. They both have a C: drive though.

How can I configure the *Performance* tab to also show information for the first drive?

Update: Waid Johnson's answer worked well for one of the systems I am looking at. The system that is not working has Intel Rapid Storage Technology enabled, and there is a cache on Disk 1 that caches Disk 0.

Comment: Does http://superuser.com/q/498844/213131 help?

Comment: @Twisty It is the same asWaid Johnson's answer for diskperf, lodctr did not change anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only drives that have Write Caching enabled will show up in Taskmgr. So open device manager, select the drive, go to the option and [activate write caching](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21904-disk-write-caching-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I never checked the Device Manager. Now I see that my disk 0 is missing, I only see disk 1. I never checked since my C: partition of disk 0 is very much present in explorer. I will investigate if that is due to Intel RST SSD caching and some glitch there.

Comment: I will accept since this helped me to solve my problem. (Thanks @Waid Johnson again too!) After finding out that the device was missing from device manager, I uninstalled the Intel SATA controller and disabled the SSD cache of RST. After a reboot, disc 0 was in device manager again and also in task manager performance tab. After reenabling SSD cache, it has remained there, so it is working well enough.

Comment: i have this enabled on both of my drives and its still missing, win2012 r2

Comment: @acme64 server hide it by default. Run **diskperf -Y** to enable it. this is not required for client systems, only for server.

Answer (score 27):

Try giving this a shot:

1. Ensure Task Manager is closed.
2. Launch the Command Prompt using the *Run as Administrator* option.
3. Enter the following at the Command Prompt:

   ```
   diskperf -Y
   ```
4. Hit Enter.
5. Close the Command Prompt.
6. Re-open the Task Manager.

PD: This command is to unhide the disk activity only in Windows Server Family. It wont work on Windows 10/11 or any other desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this has not changed anything.

Comment: It did not work on Windows 10, it worked for the Windows 2012R2 system though. I will update the question, perhaps there is a link to Intel RST (SSD cache for C: drive) on the Win 10 system.

Comment: worked for win2012 r2, thank you.

Comment: Works on Server 2016 as well.

Comment: also worked on server 2019

Comment: Its important to add that this command is Server oriented, that disk activity is hidden by default.